# How to get the printer device font list in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts, driver, printers

Is there a way to get the printer device fonts list and not the ones installed on Windows using WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using PInovke you can access printer device context and enumerate its specific font, as explained in [this](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/gdi32/EnumFontFamilies.html).

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public static class GdiFonts
{    
    #region gdi32
    
    public enum FontMask
    {
        RASTER_FONTTYPE = 0x0001,
        DEVICE_FONTTYPE = 0x0002,
        TRUETYPE_FONTTYPE = 0x0004
    }
    
    public enum FontWeight
    {
        FW_DONTCARE = 0,
        FW_THIN = 100,
        FW_EXTRALIGHT = 200,
        FW_LIGHT = 300,
        FW_NORMAL = 400,
        FW_MEDIUM = 500,
        FW_SEMIBOLD = 600,
        FW_BOLD = 700,
        FW_EXTRABOLD = 800,
        FW_HEAVY = 900
    }
    
    public enum FontPitch : int
    {
        DEFAULT_PITCH = 0,
        FIXED_PITCH = 1,
        VARIABLE_PITCH = 2,
        MONO_FONT = 8
    }
    
    public enum FontFamily
    {
        FF_DONTCARE = 0 << 4,
        FF_ROMAN = 1 << 4,
        FF_SWISS = 2 << 4,
        FF_MODERN = 3 << 4,
        FF_SCRIPT = 4 << 4,
        FF_DECORATIVE = 5 << 4
    }
    
    public enum FontMappingMode
    {
        MM_TEXT = 1,
        MM_LOMETRIC = 2,
        MM_HIMETRIC = 3,
        MM_LOENGLISH = 4,
        MM_HIENGLISH = 5,
        MM_TWIPS = 6,
        MM_ISOTROPIC = 7,
        MM_ANISOTROPIC = 8
    }
    
    public enum FontLanguageCharSet
    {
        ANSI_CHARSET = 0x00000000,
        DEFAULT_CHARSET = 0x00000001,
        SYMBOL_CHARSET = 0x00000002,
        MAC_CHARSET = 0x0000004D,
        SHIFTJIS_CHARSET = 0x00000080,
        HANGUL_CHARSET = 0x00000081,
        JOHAB_CHARSET = 0x00000082,
        GB2312_CHARSET = 0x00000086,
        CHINESEBIG5_CHARSET = 0x00000088,
        GREEK_CHARSET = 0x000000A1,
        TURKISH_CHARSET = 0x000000A2,
        VIETNAMESE_CHARSET = 0x000000A3,
        HEBREW_CHARSET = 0x000000B1,
        ARABIC_CHARSET = 0x000000B2,
        BALTIC_CHARSET = 0x000000BA,
        RUSSIAN_CHARSET = 0x000000CC,
        THAI_CHARSET = 0x000000DE,
        EASTEUROPE_CHARSET = 0x000000EE,
        OEM_CHARSET = 0x000000FF
    }
    
    public const Int32 LF_FACESIZE = 32; // ref WinGDI.h
    public const Int32 LF_FULLFACESIZE = 64; // ref WinGDI.h
    
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public struct LOGFONT
    {
        public Int32 lfHeight;
        public Int32 lfWidth;
        public Int32 lfEscapement;
        public Int32 lfOrientation;
        public Int32 lfWeight;
        public Byte lfItalic;
        public Byte lfUnderline;
        public Byte lfStrikeOut;
        public Byte lfCharSet;
        public Byte lfOutPrecision;
        public Byte lfClipPrecision;
        public Byte lfQuality;
        public Byte lfPitchAndFamily;
        
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = LF_FACESIZE)]
        public String lfFaceName;
    }
    
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public struct TEXTMETRIC
    {
        public Int32 tmHeight;
        public Int32 tmAscent;
        public Int32 tmDescent;
        public Int32 tmInternalLeading;
        public Int32 tmExternalLeading;
        public Int32 tmAveCharWidth;
        public Int32 tmMaxCharWidth;
        public Int32 tmWeight;
        public Int32 tmOverhang;
        public Int32 tmDigitizedAspectX;
        public Int32 tmDigitizedAspectY;
        public Char tmFirstChar;
        public Char tmLastChar;
        public Char tmDefaultChar;
        public Char tmBreakChar;
        public Byte tmItalic;
        public Byte tmUnderlined;
        public Byte tmStruckOut;
        public Byte tmPitchAndFamily;
        public Byte tmCharSet;
    }
    
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public struct ENUMLOGFONT
    {
        public LOGFONT elfLogFont;
        
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = LF_FULLFACESIZE)]
        public String elfFullName;
        
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = LF_FACESIZE)]
        public String elfStyle;
    }
    
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public struct NEWTEXTMETRIC
    {
        public Int32 tmHeight;
        public Int32 tmAscent;
        public Int32 tmDescent;
        public Int32 tmInternalLeading;
        public Int32 tmExternalLeading;
        public Int32 tmAveCharWidth;
        public Int32 tmMaxCharWidth;
        public Int32 tmWeight;
        public Int32 tmOverhang;
        public Int32 tmDigitizedAspectX;
        public Int32 tmDigitizedAspectY;
        public Char tmFirstChar;
        public Char tmLastChar;
        public Char tmDefaultChar;
        public Char tmBreakChar;
        public Byte tmItalic;
        public Byte tmUnderlined;
        public Byte tmStruckOut;
        public Byte tmPitchAndFamily;
        public Byte tmCharSet;
        public UInt32 ntmFlags;
        public UInt32 ntmSizeEM;
        public UInt32 ntmCellHeight;
        public UInt32 ntmAvgWidth;
    }
    
    public struct FontData
    {
        public ENUMLOGFONT LogFont;
        public NEWTEXTMETRIC TextMetric;
        public uint FontType;
    }
    
    [DllImport("gdi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public extern static Int32 EnumFontFamiliesEx(IntPtr hdc, ref LOGFONT lpLogfont, FONTENUMPROC lpEnumFontFamExProc, IntPtr lParam, UInt32 dwFlags);
    
    
    public delegate Int32 FONTENUMPROC(ref ENUMLOGFONT lpelf, ref NEWTEXTMETRIC lpntm, UInt32 FontType, IntPtr lParam);
    public static int EnumFontFamExProc(ref ENUMLOGFONT lpelf, ref NEWTEXTMETRIC lpntm, uint FontType, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        allFontData.Add(new FontData() { LogFont = lpelf, TextMetric = lpntm, FontType = FontType });
        return 1;
    }
    
    #endregion

    private static List<FontData> allFontData;
    public static List<FontData> GetAllFonts(IntPtr hdc) 
    {
        allFontData = new List<FontData>();
        Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero);
        try
        {           
            var logfont = new LOGFONT() { lfCharSet = (byte)FontLanguageCharSet.DEFAULT_CHARSET };
            EnumFontFamiliesEx(hdc, ref logfont, new FONTENUMPROC(EnumFontFamExProc), IntPtr.Zero, 0);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            //graphics.ReleaseHdc();
        }
        
        return allFontData;
    }
}
```

The hdc passed to `GetAllFonts(IntPtr hdc)` is obtained throught the folowing code:

```
[DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr CreateDC(string strDriver, string strDevice, string strOutput, IntPtr pData);

...
IntPtr hdc = CreateDC("", yourPrinterName, "", System.IntPtr.Zero);
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I finally succeeded!!